# Defeating the Async Quagmire

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am attempting to do a RouteQuery but it only allows for async calls. Unfortunately when the return is hit it hasn't finished the QueryAsync()

Is there a standard way around this?

Usually I would just start a timer and wait for a property to populate but that is way to ghetto. There has to be a solution for this.

```
private bool wayPointHit(GeoCoordinate geo)
{
    RouteQuery query = new RouteQuery();
    List<GeoCoordinate> coords = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
    coords.Add(new GeoCoordinate(curLocation.Latitude, curLocation.Longitude));
    coords.Add(geo);

    query.Waypoints = coords;
    bool hit = false;

    query.QueryCompleted +=  (sender, args)  =>
    {
        var rt = args.Result;
        if (rt.LengthInMeters <= 20)
        {
            hit = true;

        }
    };
    query.QueryAsync();

    return hit;
}
```

Comment: The whole idea of async is not to wait until operation is completed (that would be sync) but to start the query, and get back to other stuff. The query result should be handled by callback code.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek trust me if I could do i synchronously I would. However Windows Phone is all async, all the time.

Comment: Yes, because sync would make the UI freeze, what is not really recommended. And if platform is async-oriented you have to program in async-oriented way too. Don't try make your code as if it was sync, because system doesn't allow that.

Comment: Okay I got what you are saying and its great. You aren't really offering a solution to this problem though. I know that I need to stick with asynchronous solutions. I have. That's why I am having this issue.

Comment: I'm not giving you  the solution, because they might be no solution here. It might be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you might be trying to fix the wrong problem (possibly you need to change your design, not the method). btw. is that WP8 or WP7.5?

Comment: Given who you are and your experience I will go to bed and look at it with fresh eyes in the morning. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: And it's Windows Phone 8

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I ended up rewriting it to be async compliant

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek they'll say I am crazy but I saw the answer in a dream. Turns out it works.